# Javascript Class Inheritance not working as it should

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

Trying to create some Javascript classes and parent classes, and not sure if I'm doing this correctly, but super() in the child class isn't working as it should. Trying to get content in DivElement to work, but it keeps returning undefined.

Code:

```
 class HTMLElement{
    constructor(tag, content){
        this.tag = tag;
        this.content = content;
    }

    render(){
        return `<${this.tag}>${this.content}</${this.tag}>`;
    }

class DivElement extends HTMLElement{
constructor(content){
    super(content);
    this.tag = 'div';
   }

 }

let div1 = new DivElement('test');
console.log(div1);
console.log(div1.render());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The super call should match the signature of the target method. It should read `super('div', content);`:

```
class HTMLElement{
    constructor(tag, content){
        this.tag = tag;
        this.content = content;
    }

    render(){
        return `<${this.tag}>${this.content}</${this.tag}>`;
    }
 }

class DivElement extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(content){
    super('div', content);  // changed here
    this.tag = 'div';
   }

 }

let div1 = new DivElement('test');
console.log(div1);
console.log(div1.render());
// <div>test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of the HTMLElement class is called with two parameters (tag & content). The extended class calls the constructor with only one parameter and assigns content to the tag parameter of the parent class. Note that JS does not allow constructor overloading.

See the answer of Glycerine.